# p:commandButton not working within a p:dataTable while using filter

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using JSF, Primefaces 5.2 and  GlassFish 4.1.

I have set up a simple project to test and replicate my larger issue and found it is repeatable within the test project.

I have a simple page with a simple list of objects.  I am using the `<p:dataTable>` and using the global search capability and pagination.

**Table Code**

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="carsForm" >
        <p:dataTable id="singleDT" var="c" value="#{testFlow.cars}" widgetVar="carsTable" rows="10" paginator="true"
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" emptyMessage="No cars found with the given criteria" reflow="true"
                     filteredValue="#{testFlow.filteredCars}">

            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:outputPanel class="fright">
                    <h:outputText value="Search all fields: " />
                    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('carsTable').filter()" style="width:200px" placeholder="Enter keyword" />
                </p:outputPanel>
                <p:outputPanel class="Fleft">
                    <p:commandButton value="New Car" action="addCar" />
                </p:outputPanel>
                <div class="EmptyBox5"></div>
            </f:facet>

            <p:column filterBy="#{c.id}" headerText="ID" sortBy="#{c.id}" >
                <h:outputText value="#{c.id}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column filterBy="#{c.m}" headerText="Model Year" sortBy="#{c.modelYear}" >
                <h:outputText value="#{c.modelYear}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column filterBy="#{c.make}" headerText="Make" sortBy="#{c.make}" >
                <h:outputText value="#{c.make}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column filterBy="#{c.model}" headerText="Model" sortBy="#{c.model}" >
                <h:outputText value="#{c.model}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column filterBy="#{c.color}" headerText="Color" sortBy="#{c.color}" >
                <h:outputText value="#{c.color}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="width: 200px; text-align: center">
                <p:commandButton actionListener="#{testFlow.removeCar(c)}" value="Delete" update="singleDT messages" ajax="true" >
                    <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

        <div class="EmptyBox5"></div>
        <p:panel>
            <p:commandButton action="returnFromTestFlow" value="Exit the Flow" />
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>

    <p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

    <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">
        <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
        <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
    </p:confirmDialog>
</ui:define>
```

My Controller has a simple method to remove the object.

**Method**

```
public String removeCar(Inventory c) {
    String redirectTo = "/testFlow/testFlow";

    try {
        this.cars.remove(c);
        iFacade.remove(c);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return redirectTo;
}
```

When I remove all the filtering and sorting, the method is called after I click yes and the row is deleted.  While the filtering and sorting is in place, however, the entire table just re displays as empty but no method is ever called.  No error appears, and while using the debugger it never hits a break-point within the method in question.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that the datatable is first rendered using the list you provided, but when you press a button it searches through the filtered list and since this is empty at first it cannot locate the button. Notice on the other hand, that if you enter a search criteria and delete it again, the buttons work. This is because the filtered list has been populated and the button can now be located. To solve this problem you need to populate the filtered list with all the values pre render. In your case:

**In your backing bean:**

```
public void init()
{
    if(!FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback())
    {
        filteredCars = cars;
    }
}
```

**In your xhtml file:**

```
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{testFlow.init}"/>;
```

Another way is using the `@PostConstruct` annotation on your init() function instead of `<f:event type="preRenderView />`which is clearer code, but, in my opinion, a bit vague in terms of when the function is called.

Comment: Thank you ! I was stuck 3 hours on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, @djst solution didn't work for me, but I ended up fixing the problem by using Omnifaces form (`o:form`) instead of standard `h:form`. Not sure why, though, but may be worth a try.

Answer (score -1):

When you are using the filtering, primefaces creates a list and shows it in the result, when you are deleting an item from the main list, it has nothing to do with the display list, and this may cause problems like what happened to you.

Comment: But what should be done to fix it? Now it is more of a comment than an answer

Comment: I should add that this happens on the unfiltered list as well as the filtered list. Also, when using either action= or actionListener=,  the result is the same.